# fullcalendar dayagenda fixed time on left

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

is there are way to fix the day display on left of day view in fullcalendar?

We group by name at the top and a horizontal scrollbar, when scrolling to the right the time scrolls with.  is there a way to fix the times on the left side and scroll

Full calendar day view

[image: full calendar dayview]

Comment: you solved it ?